# Icons not showing in react-native-multiple-select

Tags: react-native

[image]

Icons like dropdown or search is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you add and configure react-native-vector-icons..?

if not please go through this [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `react-native-vector-icons` if you did then you have to configure it for android by adding this line:
`apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"` in `android/app/build.gradle`
then you will be able to see icons.
Hope so this would be helpful for you.